# what is the python interpreter for odoo serveur (openERP)

Tags: python, linux, odoo

We use opnerp (odoo) on a linux server (debian), I want to locate the python interpreter used by the odoo daemon,

So the question is how I can change the path to my new python interpreter.

In other words, how does odoo choose its interpreter to run the modules?

Comment: What version is Debian/odoo? How it is installed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `odoo-bin` its called out like `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Paxmees , and the code is located in `Setup/odoo` , like the following :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
__import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace('odoo.addons') 
import odoo  
if __name__ == "__main__":     
   odoo.cli.main()
```